# How to add the Left margin in UITableViewCell iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, uitableview

How to add the left margin in UITableVIewCell Xamarin iOS.
I have tried the following ways but they does not work

```
public void initCell( CustomCommentInfo comment )
{
   CoreGraphics.CGRect frame = this.ContentView.Frame;
   if (comment.level > 0)
   {
      frame.X = frame.X + (comment.level * 10);
   }
   this.Frame = frame;
 }
```

and

```
public void initCell( CustomCommentInfo comment )
{
   CoreGraphics.CGRect frame = this.Frame;
   if (comment.level > 0)
   {
      frame.X = frame.X + (comment.level * 10);
   }
   this.Frame = frame;
}
```

both of these does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i tried it with an other way that works

I added the view in the cell and added left margin constraints then keep the reference to the left margin in code and change it in code works

In designer.cs

```
UIKit.NSLayoutConstraint marginCommentCell { get; set; }
```

and in code behind file

```
if (comment.level > 0)
{       
    marginCommentCell.Constant += marginCommentCell.Constant *  comment.level;
}
else {
    marginCommentCell.Constant = 10; // constant value
}
```